# What is the reason for endowing the positive semidefinite cone with the Affine Invariant Riemannian Metric instead of a Euclidean metric?

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, positive-semidefinite

I came across this post [Distances defined in manifold of symmetric positive definite matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2562148/distances-defined-in-manifold-of-symmetric-positive-definite-matrices/4885473#4885473) because I had the same questions. I did not understand the answers provided, so I wanted to try to answer it myself. Originally, I posted my justifications and intuitions as an answer, but given I do not have a background in differential geometry and was unsure about my answer, I thought it would be better to post it as a question. The two main points I was trying to address were

1. "I always pictured it as a "curved sheet" like the shell of a sphere but not the sphere itself; therefore, the idea of calling the PSD cone a manifold was confusing"
2. The main question being asked: "if I understand correctly, SPD matrices lie inside a convex set i.e. linear combinations of SPD matrices will be SPD. Intuitively, I don't see the need of defining a distance that goes along the curvature of SPD matrices since the set is dense"

Do these justifications/intuitions correctly address those questions:

1. "I always pictured it as a "curved sheet" like the shell of a sphere but not the sphere itself; therefore, the idea of calling the PSD cone a manifold was confusing"

Although it is easier to imagine a manifold as a hyper-surface, a manifold does not need to be in some ambient space of higher dimension to be a manifold. So take the PSD cone formed by the set of the set of 2x2 PSD matrices. This would be a [3 manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-manifold) since locally it is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3$. Whether that cone is in $\mathbb{R}^3$, $\mathbb{R}^4$, or $\mathbb{R}^n$ does not make a difference. i.e. Manifolds are independent of the ambient space they live/are portrayed in..

2. The main question being asked: "if I understand correctly, SPD matrices lie inside a convex set i.e. linear combinations of SPD matrices will be SPD. Intuitively, I don't see the need of defining a distance that goes along the curvature of SPD matrices since the set is dense"

Two pictures that help me conceptualize this idea. [image: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2562148/distances-defined-in-manifold-of-symmetric-positive-definite-matrices]

[image]

Picture [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zoyqf.png) is from [Riemannian geometry for EEG-based brain-computer
interfaces; a primer and a review](https://hal.science/hal-01570120/document). This shows that the boundary is defined by the set of PSD matrices with determinant of 0 and that the interior of the cone contains positive definite matrices with a non zero determinant.

Picture [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ndnpk.png) is from [A pictorial representation of the positive semidefinite cone](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/A-pictorial-representation-of-the-positive-semidefinite-cone-S-d-n-Viewing-matrices_fig1_327946536) and is how I am viewing the PSD cone in practice. I am not sure if this is correct, but my interpretation is that the PSD cone can be viewed as a solid cone made up of infinitely many layers (level-sets) of other cones, where each layer of cone has a certain determinant (however, in this picture each layer of this cone looks like it includes the origin, but in the situation I am describing only the boundary when determinant is 0 would the origin be included). Every matrix on the outside boundary has a determinant of 0, every matrix on the next layer which is in the interior of the boundary has a determinant slightly greater than 0, and so on. As I explain below, I believe in practice, a set of sample covariance matrices usually come from one layer/a group of layers near the boundary. This idea is touched on in these posts [Is the set of symmetric positive semi-definite matrices a smooth manifold with boundary](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3571464/is-the-set-of-symmetric-positive-semi-definite-matrices-a-smooth-manifold-with-b) and [Positive semidefinite cone is generated by all rank-1 matrices.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/678693/positive-semidefinite-cone-is-generated-by-all-rank-1-matrices?rq=1).

I think theoretically if your sample covariance matrices were positive definite and had varying determinants than using Euclidean distance to measure the distance would make sense, since the PSD cone is an open convex set and has a non-empty interior with positive volume. However, in practice the sample covariance matrices are usually ill conditioned (eigenvalues lower in the spectrum are closer to zero) due to redundancies in the data. The way I see it is that this means two things. One, the data we are modeling is really close to the surface of the psd cone (at the surface the determinant is 0 and ill conditioned matrices have determinants approaching 0) which means they resemble something closer to the subset of PSD matrices which have determinant equal to 0. Two, the covariance matrices we are modeling have similar determinants which implies they live on some curved sub-manifold/layer of the psd cone. For these reasons we should use the Affine Invariant Riemannian Metric . Since the set of positive semi definite and positive definite matrices is convex, as was mentioned in the original post, the straight line distance will always be further in the interior of the cone. I believe the further you move into the interior of the cone, the higher your determinant is. Assuming your data all has similar determinants, taking the arithmetic mean would cause you to end up with an average matrix that has a larger determinant than the your sample covariance matrices. By using the Affine Invariant Riemannian Metric we will avoid doing things like considering covariance matrices of higher determinants because we are following a curved path. This idea of increasing determinant and determinant identity is discussed in footnote 13 of [Riemannian geometry for EEG-based brain-computer
interfaces; a primer and a review](https://hal.science/hal-01570120/document) and Figure 4.1 in [Geometric Means In A Novel Vector Space Structure On Symmetric Positive-Definite Matrices](https://www-sop.inria.fr/asclepios/Publications/Arsigny/arsigny_siam_tensors.pdf). This paper as well discusses and references some good sources that go over some of the difference between different means/metrics on the PSD cone [Riemannian Metric and Geometric Mean for Positive Semidefinite Matrices of Fixed Rank](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0807.4462.pdf).

I visualized this idea with real data below in image [10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nfnsg.png). Here I plotted the log determinant of 100 covariance matrices from the same class. I used the log scale on the x axis since all the determinants were numerically close to  0 and different magnitudes away from 0. I then took the determinant of the Riemannian Mean (mean induced by the Affine Invariant Riemannian Metric) of the covariance matrices as shown in green. This seems to correctly predict the mean determinant of the covariance matrices. I also, took the determinant of the arithmetic mean of the covariance, shown in red. The arithmetic average covariance matrix seems to have a determinant that is significantly higher than the class the average came from.

[image]

Comment: Neither question 1 nor question 2 make much sense. It seems that the person who asked these questions does not know what a manifold is and what the curvature is, while using this terminology.

Comment: My suggestion is for you to figure out what kind of a question **you** would like to ask in relation to the cone of PSD matrices. In particular, does your text answer any questions **you** are interested in?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Yes, I was interested in the answers to the main points I listed. I provided my answers, but since I do not have background in this field, I was unsure if my points/understanding/use of terminology were correct, so I wanted to see if someone could confirm or correct it.

Comment: As I said, the questions make very little sense as stated. Unless the author of the original questions comes and clarifies the questions, your question is unanswerable, unless by an answer one means an explanation why do the questions make no sense and are based on misunderstanding and misuse of basic notions of differential geometry. A reasonable question would be "What are applications of non-flat metrics on the cone of PSD matrices?"

Comment: @MoisheKohan Here is how I interpreted their questions 1. Does a manifold need to be a hypersurface to be a manifold? 2. Given that the set of SPD matrices forms a convex cone and that linear combinations of SPD matrices remain SPD, why do we often define a Riemannian metric that takes into account the curvature of this set, rather than using a simpler, flat metric?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Do these questions make sense and do my provided answers correctly address these questions? (For the second question I understand it is application specific so there could be many reasons that lead to the choice of a metric, but is the one I provided a common reason as to why the affine invariant metric is chosen in practice?)

Comment: The first question is awkwardly stated but makes sense (and the answer is "absolutely not", but I do not see this written anywhere in your answer), while the second question does not make sense. As for your example of an application - I have no idea. Applications that I know are completely different.

Comment: @MoisheKohan How would you restate the first question to make it less awkward? Additionally, although it does not say absolutely not, is there anything incorrect/unrelated in the answer I provided?

As for the second question, I am trying to ask and answer why people use the affine invariant metric instead of the euclidean metric. What would be the correct way to phrase that?

Comment: A proper way to restate the 1st question would be "If $M$ is a manifold, does $M$ have to be a hypersurface in some $\mathbb R^N$." You pretty much just stated the question that should have been asked, except "affine" is strange and it is better to say "invariant under $GL(n,\mathbb R)$" (or $SL(n,\mathbb R)$, depending on the precise setup). As for your answer to 1, it is a mixture of correct and incorrect.

Comment: @MoisheKohan That makes sense, but I was specifically referring to a metric I have seen in literature called the Affine Invariant Riemannian Metric (https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7740054), but I should have capitalized it and added the full name and source to avoid confusion. Would you be able to expand upon which parts of the first question (and or the second) are correct and incorrect? Thank you for the clarifications

Comment: I guess it is a difference between pure and applied math: in pure math one does not use the terminology "Affine Invariant Riemannian Metric" for this metric.

Answer (score 1):

> Although it is easier to imagine a manifold as a hyper-surface, a manifold does not need to be in some ambient space of higher dimension to be a manifold.

Validity of the 1st sentence depends on its interpretation. In modern topology and differential geometry, manifolds are indeed abstract and are not considered as subsets of some "ambient space." Nevertheless, every manifold $M$ is naturally embedded as a hypersurface in $M\times \mathbb R$. But, most likely, in the original question it was meant to be a hypersurface in some Euclidean space. Then the answer is that there are, for instance, surfaces, which cannot be embedded in $\mathbb R^3$, e.g. the projective plane and the Klein bottle.

> So take the PSD cone formed by the set of the set of 2x2 PSD matrices. This would be a [3 manifold][1] since locally it is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3$.

This is correct but, actually, it is not only locally diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3$, but is globally diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3$. A bit cleaner statement would be:

The PSD cone $S_2^+$ is an open subset of the 3-dimensional real vector space $S_2$ of symmetric $2\times 2$ matrices. Hence, $S_2^+$ has a natural structure of a differentiable 3-dimensional manifold. As such, it is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^3$.

> Whether that cone is in $\mathbb{R}^3$, $\mathbb{R}^4$, or $\mathbb{R}^n$ does not make a difference. i.e. Manifolds are independent of the ambient space they live/are portrayed in.

One cannot say "manifolds are independent." One can say that "being a topological manifold is an intrinsic property of a topological space and has nothing to do with its embedding, if it happens to be embedded in an ambient topological space." One can make a similar statement about differentiable manifolds, for instance:

A differentiable manifold is a topological space equipped with an atlas of charts satisfying certain properties. It is a theorem that every $n$-dimensional manifold can be embedded in $\mathbb R^{2n}$ but such an embedding does not change the intrinsic properties of the manifold.

Unstated in all this is the fact that the author of the original questions probably did not even mean a differentiable manifold but had in mind Riemannian manifolds. Only once you equip a manifold with a Riemannian metric (or a semi-Riemannian metric), you can talk about its curvature.